# jQuery / Coffeescript hide related names except $(this), won't allow me to check the select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have elements which are select boxes that have "correct_answer" in their names. I want to select one box, and hide all the rest on the page. When I click a given select box with my current code, it hides all the other boxes except the one I clicked, just like I want, but then the check doesn't show up in the box,and the box is no longer functional. Any suggestions? Here is my code in coffeescript:

```
jQuery ->
$('input[name*="correct_answer"]').on "click", (event) ->
    $('input[name*="correct_answer"]').hide()
    $(this).show()
    event.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

because you are calling `preventDefault()`, the default action of the click is to change the checked state of the checkbox, also it is better to use the change event

```
jQuery ->
$('input[name*="correct_answer"]').on "change", (event) ->
    $('input[name*="correct_answer"]').hide()
    $(this).show()
```

---

Or

```
jQuery ->
    $checks = $('input[name*="correct_answer"]').on "change", (event) ->
        $checks.not(this).hide()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hN8LZ/)